# Why update is not showing for all user when app transfer to new app store account?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store, provisioning-profile

I have published apps to app store from an account & suppose my team was TeamA. So application identifier was abc123.com.companyname.appname.

Now I have transferred the app to my new account. So now when i am going to launch an update i have encountered an error like below :

```
"WARNING ITMS-90076" Potential Loss of Keychain Access. The previous version of the software has an application-identifier value of ['abc123.com.companyname.appname'] and the new version of software being submitted has an application-identifier of ['xyz456.com.companyname.appname']. This will result in a loss of keychain access
```

I have ignored the problem & published the build to the app store. After review, the app has been published. But it is not showing the update of the previous version (People who install the app which is published by TeamA). So when those users go to this appstore it is showing open action not update option.

How can i show this new version to update of the previous version for all user ?

Please help me.

Comment: Why did you change the bundle id? It should have remained the same

Comment: @Paulw11 bundle id was the same com.companyname.appname. But application identifier has been changed as team id changed. So in xcode the bundle identifier is same. but for TeamA application identifier was abc123 but for the new team(TeamB) application identifier is xyz456.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the bundle identifier , then it's considered as a different app. You should not change the bundle identifier if you want to give updates to your old users. Transfer the app again with the same identifier to your new account.

Comment: I did not change the bundle identifier. If I change bundle identifier then when I upload the build from Xcode itunes connect would not receive the build for the same app. abc123 and xyz456 is application identifier which is changed as we had to change team.